# Add data-binding for DataGridTemplateColumn created in code

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn

**The question:**

Is there a way to define a `DataTemplate` in XAML and instantiate it in code (rather than retrieve singleton by `FindResource`) and modify its `VisualTree` before sending to where a `DataTemplate` is required such as `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`?

**Background:**

I am displaying a 2-dimensional array `data[][]` in a `DataGrid` by adding `DataGridTemplateColumn` columns on my own and there is a `DataTemplate` defined in XAML that knows how to present each element in the array. However the default `DataContext` for each cell is the row, i.e. `data[x]`. So I need to "parameterize" the `DataTemplate` for each column by setting the root visual element's `DataContext` to binding `"[y]"` where `y` is the column index. Currently the `DataTemplate` is defined as in `DataGrid.Resources` and retrieved by `FindResource()` which is returning the same instance every time. Besides calling `LoadContent()` gives me the `UIElement` tree rather than loading the `VisualTree` on the `DataTemplate` itself. I am looking for a way to instantiate the `DataTemplate` in code, do the desired modification and set to `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by Sisyphe's answer, I found this more portable solution:

```
public class DataGridBoundTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public string BindingPath { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
        element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.BindingPath));
        return element;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.BindingPath));
        return element;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var cellTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.dataGrid.FindResource("cellTemplate");
foreach (var c in data.Columns)
{
    var col = new DataGridBoundTemplateColumn
    {
        Header = c.HeaderText,
        CellTemplate = cellTemplate,
        BindingPath = string.Format("[{0}]", c.Index)
    };

    this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Hope this helps someone who has the same requirement as the one in my question.

Comment: That's a very interresting answer. I didn't know the virtual methods GenerateEditingElement and GenerateElement. I'm probably going to use this in my project ! Thanks a lot for this and for the bounty !

Answer (score 1):

```
(templateKey as DataTemplate).LoadContent()
```

**Description:**
When you call `LoadContent`, the `UIElement` objects in the `DataTemplate` are created, and you can add them to the visual tree of another `UIElement`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I understand correctly, LoadContent() doesn't return a new DataTemplate, but I need a DataTemplate instance to feed  DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.

Comment: @NS.X.  LoadContent is a method of DataTemplate class and create new instance of UIElement in DataTemplate.

Comment: I see. I need a way to create new instance of the DataTemplate, not only the UIElement within it.

Comment: Ok, but you could not customize a DataTemplate unless you define each datatemplate in resource and use DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: `(x as Y).Z()` is a bad choice.  Why not `(Y)x.Z()`?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone You would need ((Y)x).Z() due to operator precedence. Otherwise, I don't see why it is a bad choice.

Comment: @Alan - Ah true.  Because `NullReferenceException` is less explanatory than `InvalidCastException` I think - and `InvalidCastException` directly explains the problem, if it happens

Answer (score 1):

You should see `DataTemplate` in WPF as a Factory. Thus I think that you don't really need a new instance of the `DataTemplate`, you just want it to be applied differently based on your context.

If I understand correctly your issue, the problem is that the `DataContext` of your `DataGrid` Cells is not correct : it's the Row ViewModel whereas you want it to be the Cell ViewModel (which makes perfect sense). This is however the basic behavior of the DataGrid and is probably tied to the fact that Cells in each rows are hold by a [DataGridCellsPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcellspresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is basically an `ItemsControl`) whose `ItemsSource` dependency property has not been set (thus explaining the bad `DataContext`).

I've run into this problem and found two way to fix this (but I only managed to make one work).

First one is to subclass [DataGridCellsPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcellspresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override `OnItemChanged` method to set the ItemsSource manually.

```
protected override void OnItemChanged(object oldItem, object newItem)
{
    var rowViewModel = newItem as ViewModel;
    if (rowViewModel != null)
    {
        ItemsSource = rowViewModel.Items;
    }
    else
    {
        ItemsSource = null;
    }
}
```

where rowViewModel.Items should point to something like data[x] in your case. However I ran into some troubles using this fix and couldnt make it work correctly.

Second solution is to subclass `DataGridCell` and update the dataContext on change of the `ColumnProperty`. You also have to subclass `DataGridCellsPresenter` to make it create the right cell controls

```
public class MyDataGridCell : DataGridCell
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == ColumnProperty)
        {
            var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModelType;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                var column = (e.NewValue as DataGridTemplateColumn);
                if (column != null)
                {
                    var cellViewModel = viewModel[column.DisplayIndex];
                    DataContext = cellViewModel;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}

public class MyDataGridCellsPresenterControl : DataGridCellsPresenter
{
    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyDataGridCell();
    }
}
```

Finally you will also have to override the DataGridRow default ControlTemplate to make it use your custom `DataGridCellsPresenter` in place of the original `DataGridCellsPresenter`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridRowControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:MyDataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}">
                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation>
                    <Binding Path="AreRowDetailsFrozen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                            <SelectiveScrollingOrientation>Vertical</SelectiveScrollingOrientation>
                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                    </Binding>
                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation>
            </DataGridDetailsPresenter>
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical">
                <DataGridRowHeader.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                            <DataGridHeadersVisibility>Row</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridRowHeader.Visibility>
            </DataGridRowHeader>
        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: You understood my issue precisely. The solution is not along the line of my question but looks promising to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to pop on the WPF chat room if you need more help on this issue ;)